# Prevent React-router-dom to refresh the page and reset the information entered on click

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router

My problem is that `react-router-dom` resets the different states of my app.
For example if a note is entered in the note category, and then I click on 'music' and then go back to the notes, they will have disappeared on refresh.

The same for my header, where I included a button to enlarge the window and another to reduce it. If I am in the 'note' category and I enlarge the window. And I navigate to 'music' or 'inbox', the window size will reset to the original size. And it will not keep the css class that the button injected.

App

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>

                <div className="window" id="window" >
                    <div className="window-body" >
                        <HeaderType />
                        <div className='window_inner'>
                            <ColumnLeft />
                            <ColumnRight />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="addWindowBody" id="openWindow">
                    <a href='/'>
                        <div className="addWindow">
                            <div class="material-symbols-outlined" >
                                open_in_full
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div className="addDarkMode"></div>

            </>

        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

ColumnLeft

```
class ColumnLeft extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="column_left">
                    <a href="/note" className='link'>
                        <div className="elements">
                            Prendre des notes
                            <span className="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a href="/inbox" className='link'>
                        <div className="elements">
                            Envoyer un message
                            <span className="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <a href="/music" className='link'>
                        <div className="elements">
                            Ecouter de la musique
                            <span className="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ColumnLeft;
```

ColumnRight

```
class ColumnRight extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="column_right">
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/"  />
                            <Route path="/note" element={<Note />} />
                            <Route path="/inbox" element={<Inbox />} />
                            <Route path="/music" element={<Music />} />
                        </Routes>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ColumnRight;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Link` component with target path on the `to` prop instead of raw anchor tags with `href` attribute to issue internal navigation actions to the other routes your app handles. The raw anchor tag is reloading the page, and thus reloads the app. In other words, the React app is remounting.

Move the `BrowserRouter` component higher in the ReactTree such that it is providing a routing context to the entire app. This is so the links in `ColumnLeft` ***and*** the routes in `ColumnRight` access the same routing context for routing and navigation purposes.

Example:

App

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="window" id="window">
          <div className="window-body">
            <HeaderType />
            <div className='window_inner'>
              <ColumnLeft />
              <ColumnRight />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="addWindowBody" id="openWindow">
          <Link to='/'>
            <div className="addWindow">
              <div class="material-symbols-outlined">
                open_in_full
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="addDarkMode" />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

ColumnLeft

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ColumnLeft extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="column_left">
        <Link to="/note" className='link'>
          <div className="elements">
            Prendre des notes
            <span className="line" />
          </div>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/inbox" className='link'>
          <div className="elements">
            Envoyer un message
            <span className="line" />
          </div>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/music" className='link'>
          <div className="elements">
            Ecouter de la musique
            <span className="line" />
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ColumnRight

```
class ColumnRight extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="column_right">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/note" element={<Note />} />
          <Route path="/inbox" element={<Inbox />} />
          <Route path="/music" element={<Music />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```